# Remove specific items in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For example (see screen-1 / screen-2) : When i first click on the delete button, it works, the specific item is well remove on the LocalStorage, but after that if I click on another item (like the 3rd element), an other element is remove (here 4) on the localStorage. (view screen-3)

[image: screen-1]
[image: screen-2]
[image: screen-3]

Then, if I refresh the page after deleting some elements, and i create new task element, the delete button don't works at all anymore.

This is what I tried with "iconDelete.addEventListener"

```
let inputNewTask = document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
let tasksContainer = document.querySelector("#tasks-container");
let tasksCompletedContainer = document.querySelector("#completed-tasks-container");
let formAddTask = document.querySelector("#form-add-task");

let tasksList = [];
let completedTasksList = [];
let tasksID = 1;

function genererTasks(){
    const listTasksJson = window.localStorage.getItem("Tasks name");
    const listTasks = JSON.parse(listTasksJson);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < listTasks.length; i++){
        
        let newTaskContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newTaskContainer.classList.add("new-task-container");
        let newTaskInput = document.createElement("input");
        newTaskInput.classList.add("input-style", "task-content");
        newTaskInput.id = "task-" + tasksID;
        tasksID = tasksID + 1;
        newTaskInput.type = "text";
        newTaskInput.value = listTasks[i];
        newTaskInput.textContent = listTasks[i].value;
        
        let iconDelete = document.createElement("i");
        iconDelete.classList.add("fa-regular", "fa-circle", "btn-style");

        tasksContainer.appendChild(newTaskContainer);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(iconDelete);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(newTaskInput);
        
        tasksList.push(listTasks[i]);

 iconDelete.addEventListener("click", function(){

            tasksContainer.removeChild(newTaskContainer);
            tasksCompletedContainer.appendChild(newTaskContainer);
            
            tasksList.splice(i,1);
            window.localStorage.setItem("Tasks name", JSON.stringify(tasksList));

        });

        newTaskInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
            updateTaskInLocalStorage(i, newTaskInput.value);
          });
    }
}

const listTasksJson = (localStorage.getItem("Tasks name") !== null);
if (listTasksJson){
    genererTasks();
}
```

````
    <body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!--Add list name h3-->
                    <h4>En cours</h4>
                    <div id="tasks-container">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="new-task-container-submit">
                        <form id="form-add-task" action="">
                            <input class="btn-style" type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="+" title="Ajouter">
                            <input class="input-style" type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="Ajouter une tâche">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Terminées</h4>
                    <div id="completed-tasks-container">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>```
````

Comment: When you delete an item, you change the index of all subsequent items. You need to update the event listeners for those items. Alternatively you can give each entry a unique id and have some way of finding an entry by id. If you want a concrete fix, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! what do you mean by "update the event listeners" ?
The thing that I understand is the index of my items in my array change when I delete an item.
My input elements have unique ID (in html).
Should I try to give to my entries an id in the LocalStorage (Don't really understand)

Comment: I'd like to help, but please read the article I linked more carefully. The code you provided doesn't even run, let alone reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i change the code it should run now. On my computer it's running but when i try to run code there I have this error : "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag."

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a small abstraction layer on top of localStorage....

```
let store;
try {
  // this might give a runtime error
  // if localStorage.store can't be parsed from JSON
  store = JSON.parse(localStorage.store);
}
catch (e) {
  // if we could not JSON.parse localStorage.store
  // then set store to an empty objecty
  store = {};
}

// Add a save method/function to store
store.save = () => localStorage.store = JSON.stringify(store);

// If needed, and using JS with import/export:
// Export the store so it can be used in other files
export default store;
```

Now you can simply add as many new properties as you want to **store**:

```
store.someNewThing = {firstName: 'New', lastName: 'Thing'};
store.save();
```

And delete things as well:

```
delete store.someNewThing;
store.save();
```

Thus writing, reading and deleting to **localStorage** becomes as uncomplicated as generic object creation (and modifying) + remembering to call **save**.